# how to group elements of a table in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I am a new member of stack and I am learning to program in r.
I have a data frame with three columns, `requete`, `id_requete` and `possition_url_cliquee`.
For each `requete` we have different `id_requete`.
For each `id_requete` we have 1 or more values ​​of `position_url_cliquee`.
I want to put the `position_url_cliquee` in a vector for each `id_requete`.
I created this function which will have to return an array with `id_requete` and associated vectors.
But it does not work as I want

```
table_data=group_by(table_data,requete,id_requete)

tab_vect=data.frame(id_requete=c(),vect=c(v[]))

vecteurs=function(table_data){
  id=table_data$id_requete[1]
  j=1
  for (i in 1:5) {
    if(id==table_data$id_requete[i]){
      v[j]=c(table_data$position_url_cliquee[i])
      j=j+1
    }
    else{
      tab_vect=rbind(id,v[j])
      j=1
      v=c()
      v[j]=c(table_data$position_url_cliquee[i])

    }
  }
  return(tab_vect)
}

tablevect=vecteurs(table_data)
```

I want to output a data frame with the different `id_requete` and associated vectors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(table_data)` after the `group_by` code line. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(table_data, 20))`.

Comment: I work on confidential data I can not publish, but it's the same form as the data frame I tested on.
here is the result of the command: ``` dput (head (table_data, 20))
structure(list(requete = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "or", class = "factor"), 
    id_requete = c(123, 123, 45, 45, 123), position_url_cliquee = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R :

```
ids <- sort(unique(table_data$id_requete))
res <- lapply(ids, function(id) sort(table_data$position_url_cliquee[table_data$id_requete == id]))
names(res) <- ids
res
```

Output :

```
$`45`
[1] 3 4

$`123`
[1] 1 2 5
```

Then to convert to a dataframe, you have to complete values with `NA` :

```
tmax <- max(sapply(res, length))
res <- lapply(res, function(r) { length(r) <- tmax; r })
as.data.frame(res)
```

Output :

```
  X45 X123
1   3    1
2   4    2
3  NA    5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it gives pretty much what I was looking for, except that I would like the output to be a data frame, I tried to convert it into a data frame but it does not give what I'm really looking for ```table_vecteur=data.frame(t(sapply(table_vecteur,c)))
 ```

Comment: @RymBoukriba it is not possible as a dataframe because you have a different number of clicks for each requete. It is possible to have a dataframe with missing values if you really need a dataframe

Comment: Yes i need a data frame , could you show how to get it even with the missing values please :) Thanks

Comment: @RymBoukriba please have a look, might worth an upvote too

Comment: or if you can help me convert the list to a data frame, I've already tried this command:      ```
tab=data.frame(t(sapply(tablevect,c))) ```
and here is its output :       ``` > tab
   X45    X123
1 3, 4 1, 2, 5```

Comment: @RymBoukriba the transformation is done in my answer. You need to add missing values when length of the result is lower than the max length